# How to get the camera app to take multiple photos and return them to the calling activity?

Tags: android-intent, camera

I have managed to get the camera app take one photo and return it to the activity using `MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`.

I also managed to get it take multiple photos by launching it in still image mode, but this doesn't return the photos taken back to the activity.

How do I get the camera take multiple photos and return them to the activity?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is possible.  It is, however, relatively easy to write your own Activity that uses the camera.  See http://developer.android.com/training/camera/cameradirect.html for details.